# How to obtain an X and Y position of the image extracted with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have the following class, which extracts the images from a pdf page. I now need to get the position of the image in the PDF. How can I get getCurrentTransformationMatrix () from the code listed below (No need to extend the PDFStreamEngine class).

````
  private final PDDocument document;
  private final String extension = "png";
  private final Path pathExtraction;

  public ImageExtractor(PDDocument document, Path pathExtraction) {
    this.document = document;
    this.pathExtraction = pathExtraction;
  }

  public void extract(int page) throws IOException {
    PDResources pdResources = document.getPage(page).getResources();
    int imageNumber = 0;
    for (COSName csName : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {
      PDXObject pdxObject = pdResources.getXObject(csName);
      
      if (pdxObject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
        PDStream pdStream = pdxObject.getStream();
        PDImageXObject image = new PDImageXObject(pdStream, pdResources);
        ImageIO.write(
            image.getImage(),
            extension,
            new File(pathExtraction.toFile() + "/img_" + imageNumber + "." + extension));
        imageNumber++;
      }
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: *"I now need to get the position of the image in the PDF"* - that might not be well-defined: The same image resource may be used in one or more places on a page or not at all!

Comment: Try the PrintImageLocations.java example, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861179/pdfbox-extract-image-location-wrong-x-and-y/  (get the source of PrintImageLocations not from the link there, rather download the current source code)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Did that link help? In that case, upvote that one and delete your question. Alternatively answer the question yourself, if you think an answer would provide extra value.